# VSCode-Docker Not Invoking "CMD"

Tags: docker, docker-compose, visual-studio

**TL;DR** Image built by VSCode only executes the CMD command when I press the Run button in the Docker Desktop UI.

Hello Folks,

I'm playing around with a Drools image along with Docker Desktop and VSCode.

My `devcontainer.json` file looks like the following:

```
{
    "name": "Existing Dockerfile",
    "build": {
        // Sets the run context to one level up instead of the .devcontainer folder.
        "context": "..",
        // Update the 'dockerFile' property if you aren't using the standard 'Dockerfile' filename.
        "dockerfile": "../Dockerfile"
    },

    // Use 'forwardPorts' to make a list of ports inside the container available locally.
    "forwardPorts": [8001,8080]
}
```

My `Dockerfile` is minimalist and looks like the following:

```
FROM quay.io/kiegroup/business-central-workbench:latest
```

And my `compose.yaml` file looks like so:

```
services:
  app:
    entrypoint:
    - sleep
    - infinity
    image: docker/dev-environments-default:stable-1
    init: true
    volumes:
    - type: bind
      source: /var/run/docker.sock
      target: /var/run/docker.sock
```

The issue is that when VSCode sends the image to Docker Desktop, the
`CMD ["./start_business-central-wb.sh"]` found in the parent image does not seem to be getting set off as seen in the logs

[image: Docker No Run Image.PNG]

However, when I click "Run" the command gets kicked off after spawning a new instance
[image]

[image]

What concept am I missing as to why the Docker image doesn't immediately begin running when VSCode sends it to Docker Desktop?  I'm super inexperienced with both techs.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I was not using `overrideCommand` in my `devcontainer.json` file.  This value when set to false allows the CMD listed in the container to run.

The following file seems to do what I believe it should be doing.

```
{
    "name": "Debian",
    "image": "quay.io/kiegroup/business-central-workbench:latest",
    "overrideCommand": false
}
```